# Numericupdown box line width

Tags: c#, numericupdown

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MiniPaint
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Graphics g;
        Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
        Point sp = new Point(0, 0);
        Point ep = new Point(0, 0);
        int k = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void red_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            p.Color = red.BackColor;
            default1.BackColor = red.BackColor;
        }

        private void green_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            p.Color = green.BackColor;
            default1.BackColor = green.BackColor;
        }

        private void blue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            p.Color = blue.BackColor;
            default1.BackColor = blue.BackColor;
        }

        private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            sp = e.Location;
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left);
            k = 1;

        }

        private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            k = 0;

        }

        private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (k == 1)
            {
                ep = e.Location;
                g = this.CreateGraphics();
                g.DrawLine(p, sp, ep);
            }

            sp = ep;

        }

        private void del1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            g.Clear(Color.White);

        }

        private void yellow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            p.Color = yellow.BackColor;
            default1.BackColor = yellow.BackColor;
        }

        private void purple_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            p.Color = purple.BackColor;
            default1.BackColor = purple.BackColor;
        }

        private void brown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            p.Color = brown.BackColor;
            default1.BackColor = brown.BackColor;
        }

        private void black_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            p.Color = black.BackColor;
            default1.BackColor = black.BackColor;
        }

        private void nud1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {





        }

        private void white_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            p.Color = white.BackColor;
            default1.BackColor = white.BackColor;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm almost done with my minipaint code in c#. I wanted to add one more thing to it and it's that I can change the thickness(width) of the line im going to draw via numericupadown box and I'm trying to make it work for over an hour. Can someone help me with it please and is there a simple way of doing it? ( nud1 is  the numereric updown box)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On numeric up down value changed event, change the thickness of the pen you're using, I would recommend storing the current color in a variable that you can assign back to your pen on the value changed event when you re-initialize.

This [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7858dt5(v=vs.110).aspx) shows details on the Pen class from System.Drawing.

```
p = new Pen(Color, (float)nud1.Value);
```

Comment: I did it and im getting this error now : CS0077 The as operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type ('int' is a non-nullable value type)

Comment: Remove the as int from the parameters. I believe Value is already an int, don't know why I put that.

Comment: And now I'm having this error : Argument 2: cannot convert from 'decimal' to 'float'

Comment: This is because nud1.Value is decimal and Pen uses float for width. Editing my post with link to reference material and updated code.

Comment: It really works! Also you've mentioned adding variable so i can assign back to my pen value when changed event hapens. Is there a way to do it without new variable? Thanks for the width problem I had !

Comment: p = new Pen(default1.BackColor, (float)nud1.Value);

Managed to do it this way! Thanks a lot once again buddy!